# Disable touch overlay layer on linked elements inside android WebView?

Tags: android, webkit, webview, android-webview

This might be a simple configuration or something, But I would like to disable blueish overlay which shows when touched on links or linked items (images or other linked stuffs) from android's WebView.

For better illustration, I've added an screenshot taken from Galaxy Tab - Honeycomb 3.1

Thanks

[image: Android Sample - WebView touch overlay for links]

Comment: I want to do this, because, I already have touch state for elements (hover styles).

Comment: I think, usage of JavaScript for webview may be done your work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution to my issue, solved using CSS:

```
body {
   /* Disable tap overlay color on links - set alpha to %0 = invisible */
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Then it should not give you touch overlay anymore :-]